# How to start activity with populated backstack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a notification that needs to start a activity `B`. However, I want to be able to let the user "go back" to the Dasboard `A`.

I am wondering how this could be done? Will I need to use a intent extra to start A and process that intent in `onCreate` and then start `B` manually? Or is it possible to manually specify a backstack?

Comment: Why do you want to 'artificially' alter the back stack? I shall use an example to help explain what I am getting at, the Facebook app shows me I have a notification. I view the new message/photo/event then press back which takes me back to where I was before I pressed on the notification. If I wanted to use the rest of the FB app I would already be using it when the event that triggered the notification occurred. So I ask - why in your app would I want to see the dashboard of your app on back press?

Comment: Yes I agree, it's a bit out of order for Android. I'll think about it.

Comment: It is not out of order. This is exactly how google recommends it, if your activity which you're going to start is not made to be "standalone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with your own solution and create an Intent to activity A and somehow tell activity A in this Intent that it should start Activity B.

This behavior is not the standard Android behavior. The user should be used to get to the last screen with the back button. I would not try to hijack this Operating System feature.

If in your case the user for example is sent to a detailview of a message through the notification, back should close your app and move back to the previous screen. If you want to give your user the possibility to go "back" from the message to the overall message inbox, use the [up navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Up) structure that can be used with the ICS Action Bar. Sounds complicated but in the essence it only means that you need to add a Button that takes the user to the Inbox. Since the introduction of the Actionbar (Summer 2010 I think) there is a standard position for this up button. It is in the upper left corner of the screen. (just like the iOS back button ;) )

Comment: Yes, that is maybe a good idea indeed. I don't have a actionbar currently, but maybe it's a good idea to look into it.

Comment: You don't need to add a full actionbar(it is not available pre Android 3.x). Just keep in mind that if you are adding an up button the user expect it to be in the upper left screen corner.

Comment: This functionality is actually recommended, see http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html, specifically the section titled "Navigation into Your App via Home Screen Widgets and Notifications."

Comment: Also, you can get real action bar functionality pre-Honeycomb with the support library, or even better ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [startActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent%5B%5D)) method to launch a complete backstack of activities in one go.

```
startActivities(
    new Intent[]
    {
        new Intent("my.intent.FOO_INTENT"),
        new Intent("my.intent.BAR_INTENT"),
        new Intent("my.intent.BAZ_INTENT")
    });
```

In this example an instance of Baz is created and made the current Activity.

If Baz finishes then an instance of Bar is created and is made the current Activity.

If Bar finishes then an instance of Foo is created and is made the current Activity.

This method was introduced in API level 16 but is [available](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#startActivities(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent[])) in the v4 support library via the [ContextCompat](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) class:

```
ContextCompat.startActivities(context,
    new Intent[]
    {
        new Intent("my.intent.FOO_INTENT"),
        new Intent("my.intent.BAR_INTENT"),
        new Intent("my.intent.BAZ_INTENT")
    });
```