# Allowing Back Navigation After Notification Access

Tags: android, notifications, onbackpressed

I have notifications in my app that upon clicking, allow a user into a messaging activity. At present, upon pressing the back navigation it simply closes out of the app and activity.

How can I configure it, so that after the back button is pressed, it opens the main activity (has drawer navigation) as well as opening the specific friend message list fragment? (and subsequently allow for further navigation within the app)

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/24680199/3378714. This is already answered here.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this in my app is to override the `onKeyDown()` method. You can also override `onBackPressed()` but that has given me problems in the past, so I do it this way.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //do any cleanup you need to do
        Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(upIntent);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To handle up navigation in an Activity that can be started from multiple other Activities, I usually pass in a String that represents the "signature" of the Activity that started the current Activity, store it, then check it later to find out where the up nav button should navigate to. Then in my `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, I check which Activity started this Activity using the stored "call signature" string, and go back to it. Like this...

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = null;
            switch(callingActivitySignature) {
                case MainActivity.CALL_SIGNATURE:
                    upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    break;
                case SecondActivity.CALL_SIGNATURE:
                    upIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                    break;
                case ThirdActivity.CALL_SIGNATURE:
                    upIntent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    break;
            }

            if(upIntent != null) {
                startActivity(upIntent);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```